# Is it possible to integrate Django Paypal IPN without using paypal_dict form?

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to use the javascript button code provided by paypal instead of the paypal_dict form passed from the view to the template.

I want to use the paypal code because of its modern design and simplicity.

I have the paypal code working well on sandbox. Specifically I am using subscriptions payment method.

**I have integrated paypal IPN in settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
   ...
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns += [

...
    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
...
```

**I have added the following to apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MypaypalConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myPaypal'

    def ready(self):
            import myPaypal.signals.handlers
```

**and here is my handlers.py file:**

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from django.utils import timezone


from Store.colors import *

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    print(sender)
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        print("ST_PP_COMPLETED")




valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

**and in my template I have the code provided by paypal:**

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id= ***" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': '***'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        // $("#confirm_form").submit()
        console.log(data)
        console.log(actions)
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

After I successfully process the payment(sandbox) I don't receive any IPN.

Is there a possible way to integrate paypal IPN this way?

Comment: Why are you integrating that old legacy service in the year 2020? Why not webhooks?

Comment: thank you; I had never heard about webhook. I am already using it. it's better than the method I was using previously.